# Create record from view in background

Tags: lightning-aura-components, list-view, javascript-controller, create-records, detail-page

I currently have a lightning component from which I want to save a string into a record. In my javascript controller I create a record when a button is clicked. A dialog is shown to save the record and after saving goes to the recorddetail page.

How can I prevent going to the record detailpage. I want to save the record on the background and stay on the current page. Thanks in advance.

Javascript controller:

```
var createSearchNotes = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
                            createSearchNotes.setParams({
                                "entityApiName": "SearchNote__c",
                                "defaultFieldValues": {
                                    'Search__c' : searchField.replaceAll("like","").replaceAll("'","")
                                }
                            });
                            createSearchNotes.fire();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Presenting my comment as answer:**

You are using the standard `createRecord` event whose default behaviour, which we cannot change - handled by `one.app` container, is to `naviagate` to record after creating. You could use apex to save the record in the background or switch to LWC, if that's an option, and use lightning/uiRecordApi's `createRecord` method.